# QMDISubWindow Beneath QMenuBar

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In my PyQt program, I have a QMenuBar that launches QMDISubWindow widgets. By default that launches it around (0, 0). I modified it so that it automatically moves the widget down (as shown below).

```
def check_position(self, y, width, height, sub_window):
    if y <= 40:
        sub_window.move(randint(0, self.width - width), randint(0, self.height - height))
        print("Sub Window Moved")
```

That moves the QMDISubWindow Down, but when in Full Screen or when dragged up, the QMDISubWindow gets (may get) underneath the QMenuBar. How would you fix that issue?

F.Y.I. Full code is available at [Github](https://github.com/DSSecret-Studios-Dev/Virtual-Desktop/blob/179be32e69a45b6a2300e8cc4ef7df9b97dbc755/main.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from random import randint

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QAction, QMenuBar, QWidget,
                             QMdiArea, QMdiSubWindow, QProxyStyle, QStyle, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import (QIcon, QPainter, QPalette, QPixmap)
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt

from Browser_Tabbed import browser_tabbed
from Calculator     import calculator
from Notepad        import notepad
from Paint          import paint
from Solitaire      import solitaire


class MDIArea(QMdiArea):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MDIArea, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        self.parent = args[0]
        self.background_pixmap = self.parent.pixmap 
        self.centered          = False
        self.display_pixmap    = None

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(self.viewport())
        if not self.centered:
            painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.background_pixmap)
        else:
            painter.fillRect(event.rect(), self.palette().color(QPalette.Window))
            x = (self.width() - self.display_pixmap.width())/2
            y = (self.height() - self.display_pixmap.height())/2
            painter.drawPixmap(x, y, self.display_pixmap)
        painter.end()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.display_pixmap = self.background_pixmap.scaled(self.parent.window_width(), 
                                                            self.parent.window_height(), 
                                                            Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

class MyProxyStyle(QProxyStyle):
    def pixelMetric(self, QStyle_PixelMetric, option=None, widget=None):
        if QStyle_PixelMetric == QStyle.PM_SmallIconSize:
            return 40
        else:
            return QProxyStyle.pixelMetric(self, QStyle_PixelMetric, option, widget)


class Desktop(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Desktop, self).__init__()
        self.widthDesktop  = 900         # widthDesktop  +++
        self.heightDesktop = 650         # heightDesktop +++

        self.title = "Remote Desktop"
        self.left  = 200 
        self.top   = 70 

        self.initUI()
        self.create_mdi()                    # +++
        self.create_menu()                   # +++

        # +++
        self.centerWidget = QWidget(self)
        layout            = QVBoxLayout()  
        layout.addWidget(self.menu)
        layout.addWidget(self.mdi)
        self.centerWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centerWidget)

        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.widthDesktop, self.heightDesktop)

    def check_position(self, y, width, height, sub_window):
#        if y <= 40:
#            sub_window.move(randint(0, self.widthDesktop - width), 
#                            randint(0, self.heightDesktop - height) ) 
        if width < 500: 
            sub_window.move(randint(0, self.widthDesktop-(int(self.widthDesktop/2))), 
                            randint(0, self.heightDesktop-(int(self.heightDesktop/2))) ) 
        else:
            sub_window.move(randint(0, self.widthDesktop-(int(self.widthDesktop/1.5))), 
                            randint(0, self.heightDesktop-(int(self.heightDesktop/1.5))) )        

        print("Sub Window Moved")

    @staticmethod
    def close_desktop():
        print("Closing Remote Desktop")
        exit(0)

    def open_browser(self):
        print("Opening Browser")
        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.setWidget(browser_tabbed.MainWindow())
        sub.setWindowTitle("Browser")
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
        widget_position = sub.pos()
        widget_dimensions = sub.frameGeometry()
        self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=sub)
        sub.show()

    def open_calculator(self):
        print("Opening Calculator")
        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.setWidget(calculator.MainWindow())
        sub.setWindowTitle("Calculator")
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
        widget_position = sub.pos()
        widget_dimensions = sub.frameGeometry()
        self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=sub)
        sub.show()

    def open_notepad(self):
        print("Opening Notepad")
        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.setWidget(notepad.MainWindow())
        sub.setWindowTitle("Notepad")
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
        widget_position = sub.pos()
        widget_dimensions = sub.frameGeometry()
        self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=sub)
        sub.show()

    def open_paint(self):
        print("Opening Paint")
        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.setWidget(paint.MainWindow())
        sub.setWindowTitle("Paint")
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
        widget_position = sub.pos()
        widget_dimensions = sub.frameGeometry()
        self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=sub)
        sub.show()

    def open_solitaire(self):
        print("Opening Solitaire")
        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.setWidget(solitaire.MainWindow())
        sub.setWindowTitle("Solitaire")
        self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
        widget_position = sub.pos()
        widget_dimensions = sub.frameGeometry()
        self.check_position(y=widget_position.y(), width=widget_dimensions.width(), height=widget_dimensions.height(), sub_window=sub)
        sub.show()

    def create_menu(self):
        self.menu = QMenuBar(self)
        self.menu.setNativeMenuBar(False)

        exitButton = QAction(QIcon("Power.jpeg"), "Exit", self)
        exitButton.setShortcut("Ctrl+Q")
        exitButton.setStatusTip("Power Off")

        browser = QAction(QIcon("browser.jpeg"), "Boron", self)
        browser.setShortcut("Ctrl+B")
        browser.setStatusTip("Open Browser")

        calculator = QAction(QIcon("Calculator.jpeg"), "Cobalt", self)
        calculator.setShortcut("Ctrl+C")
        calculator.setStatusTip("Open Calculator")

        notepad = QAction(QIcon("Notepad.png"), "Neon", self)
        notepad.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
        notepad.setStatusTip("Open Notepad")

        paint = QAction(QIcon("Paint.png"), "Paint", self)
        paint.setShortcut("Ctrl+P")
        paint.setStatusTip("Open Paint")

        solitaire = QAction(QIcon("Solitaire.jpeg"), "Xenon", self)
        solitaire.setShortcut("Ctrl+S")
        solitaire.setStatusTip("Open Solitaire")

        self.menu.addAction(exitButton)
        self.menu.addAction(browser)
        self.menu.addAction(calculator)
        self.menu.addAction(notepad)
        self.menu.addAction(paint)
        self.menu.addAction(solitaire)

        # +++
        self.menu.addAction("Cascade")
        self.menu.addAction("Tiled")
        self.menu.triggered[QAction].connect(self.windowaction)

        exitButton.triggered.connect(self.close_desktop)
        browser.triggered.connect(self.open_browser)
        calculator.triggered.connect(self.open_calculator)
        notepad.triggered.connect(self.open_notepad)
        paint.triggered.connect(self.open_paint)
        solitaire.triggered.connect(self.open_solitaire)

    # +++     
    def windowaction(self, q): 
        if q.text()=="Cascade":
            self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()
        if q.text()=="Tiled":
            self.mdi.tileSubWindows()


    def window_width(self):
        self.widthDesktop = self.width()                     # +++
        return self.widthDesktop 

    def window_height(self):
        self.heightDesktop = self.height()                   # +++
        return self.heightDesktop 

    def create_mdi(self):
        self.pixmap = QPixmap()
        self.pixmap.load("mt-mckinley.jpg")
        #self.mdi = MDIArea(self.pixmap)     
        self.mdi = MDIArea(self)
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
        #self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = Desktop()
    #ex.create_mdi()
    #ex.create_menu()
    my_style = MyProxyStyle("Fusion")
    app.setStyle(my_style)
    app.exec_()
```

[image]